# Variable with HTML content parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this variable called `$reservas` that contains a string with HTML Tables. I want to remove parts of the tables (`.tdRemove`), BEFORE I assign them to the div `#cenas`.

```
if ($reservas){
    $($reservas).find('.tdRemove').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).html());
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $("#cenas").html($reservas);
}
```

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to remove anything.
I've also tried:
`$($reservas).find('.tdRemove').remove();` and `$($reservas).remove('.tdRemove');`
Nothing works. Any suggestions?

Is there any way to tell jQuery that the variable holds html content, and should be parsed as that? If so, how? ..

Comment: Can you post an example of what the string looks like as well?

Comment: @MarkWalters - this piece of code `$($reservas)` makes the HTML string into DOM elements that can then be operated on by jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After converting your string to a jQuery object, it is now a series of DOM objects (in a document fragment) held in the jQuery object.  After removing the `.tdRemove` objects in that fragment, you can then just append that directly to your DOM.  No need to go back to HTML:

```
if ($reservas){
    var item = $($reservas);
    item.find('.tdRemove').remove();
    $("#cenas").empty().append(item);
}
```

Also, your code didn't work because the `$reservas` string of HTML was never modified.

Comment: what Mark said ^. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think, from what the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) tells me, you can only `remove()` what is already inside the DOM.

> Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

Maybe you want to add your table first, set it to ? display: none`, then filter for elements to remove and finally display the table.

```
if ($reservas) {
    $("#cenas")
        .hide()
        .html($reservas)
        .find('.tdRemove').each(function(){
            console.log($(this).html());
            $(this).remove();
        })
        .show();
}
```

Comment: This is not correct.  `.remove()` works on document fragments or elements that aren't yet inserted into the DOM.